# Custom error handling for a specific page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

If we set ENVIRONMENT to "development" will show errors but testing and live will hide them. If we set to "production" will show blank white page.

How to make a custom page no white page if we set ENVIRONMENT to "production"?

Thanks

Comment: Ok, i try.. Sorry about it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to extend Codeigniters default error handling methods for throwing exceptions.

[Custom error pages with templates in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644248/custom-error-pages-with-templates-in-codeigniter)

This however will not override PHPs errors. For that you will need to modify your code to detect an error and redirect accordingly..

[PHP custom error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033436/php-custom-error-page)